# How can I combine two columns and sort the values alphabetically?

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m new to programming languages and am trying to get the customers with the longest and shortest names, combine them in a single column, and sort them by longest then shortest names.

Here's what I have. How can I query to get my desired result in MySQL?

```sql
SELECT max(length(customer_id)) AS longest, min(length(customer_id)) AS lowest 
FROM orders
SELECT concat(longest,lowest) AS diff
FROM orders
ORDER BY diff desc
```

Table is orders

| customer_id | longest | lowest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Nathaniel | John |
| Michael |  |  |
| Nathaniel |  |  |

Expected results are:

| diff |
| --- |
| Nathaniel |
| John |

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to achieve. Give us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text (no images. no links.)

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the input data and your expected result?

Comment: I would think the easiest way to do this is two queries for the very separate lists of data, then merging them on your application front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `UNION` operator. Something like:

```sql
SELECT max(length(customer_id)) as CUSTOMER_ID
FROM orders
UNION
SELECT min(length(customer_id))
FROM orders
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(CUSTOMER_ID)
```

This should find your max and min entries and union them together into a single column named `CUSTOMER_ID`. Then you just sort them by character length.